# Inspect --module-path value at runtime

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, module-path

Is there any way to get list of directories which are included in module-path with use of `-p` or `--module-path` arguments at runtime similar to how I whold get all classpath directories using `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`?

Comment: Why do you need the `modulepath`? What use case do you have?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Just for debug purposes

Comment: The system property is `jdk.module.path`, documented in System.getProperties(). For completeness, you may want to look at the value of `jdk.module.upgrade.path`, also documented in System.getProperties().

Comment: @AlanBateman But why I don't have such systems properties even when `--module-path` was actually used? I am using java.runtime.version=9+181

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Javadoc of `System.getProperties`:

```
In addition to the standard system properties,
the system properties may include the following keys:

Key                      Description of Associated Value
jdk.module.path          The application module path
jdk.module.upgrade.path  The upgrade module path
jdk.module.main          The module name of the initial/main module
jdk.module.main.class    The main class name of the initial module
```

So you should use `System.getProperty("jdk.module.path")`

Comment: A better way would be [as suggested by Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543982/inspect-module-path-value-at-runtime#comment88100258_50543982)