# How to get SystemClassLoader URLs in JDK17 gracefully?

Tags: java, classloader, java-17

Now i am switch Jdk8 to Jdk17. In Jdk8 can use this follow code to get SystemClassLoader Urls.

```
private static URL[] getURLClassPath() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    return ((URLClassLoader) classLoader).getURLs();
}
```

but in Jdk17 , the default SystemClassLoader(AppClassLoader) is not a subclass of URLClassLoader, now i use this code to get the Urls refer to jdk17.

```
private static URL[] getURLClassPath() {
    String property = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    URL[] urls = Arrays.stream(property.split(";")).map(u -> {
        try {
            return Path.of(u).toRealPath().toFile().toURI().toURL();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).toArray(URL[]::new);
    return urls;
}
```

but i always felt it was inelegant. so have any elegant method ? best wishes and thanks a lot.

Need find any elegant method to get SystemClassLoader URLs in Jdk17.

Comment: Why is getting "java.class.path" inelegant? If anything, relying on the system class loader to be a `URLClassLoader` is *worse*.

Comment: Note that Java 17 is modular whereas Java 8 is not. Maybe you also need to consider [System] property [`jdk.module.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543982/inspect-module-path-value-at-runtime)?

Comment: Define elegant.

Comment: Why do you think you need the class path and why as an array of `URL` objects? This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Your actual problem might be solvable with the `Path` objects or even without dealing with the class path (manually).

Comment: First it is a inventory system, Second we use different ClassLoaders for class isolation, we need get the URLs of the default SystemClassLoader for loading by other custom classLoader . If there's no good way, this is it. Thanks bro.

Comment: Use `Class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`, on a class you know has been loaded by the system class loader.

Comment: “it is a inventory system” doesn’t explain anything. Then, why do your custom classloaders need the URLs of the system class loader? If they use the system class loader as parent loader, they’ll find the system classes anyway.